# Spring JPA Repository instance not created

Tags: spring, exception, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I followed the example that the Spring organization provides [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) for Spring Data JPA.

This is my repository interface:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

And this is a snippet of my Application class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.CustomerRepository] is defined
```

I tried adding a `@Repository` annotation to `CustimerRespository` and the `@ComponentScan` annotation to the `Application` class, but result is the same.

Comment: Which package does `Application` reside in? Which package does `CustomerRepository` reside in?

Comment: All classes are in the same package, with name "hello".

Comment: Any chance you can share the project?

Comment: Yes. Here is a GitHub repository: https://github.com/oanacioara/SpringJpaExample

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you dont' use Spring Boot to manage your dependencies ? i.e. : using either the [parent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html#getting-started-maven-installation) or the ["bill of material" using scope import](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` solved it.

If it doesn't work automatically, try disabling `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` and explicitly specify the repositories base package:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
}
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.app.repositories"})
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! This has helped to solve the problem with the `At least one JPA metamodel must be present!` exception. Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding on your configuration class

> @EnableJpaRepositories
>   @EnableConfigurationProperties()
>   @EntityScan({"com.project.app.entities" })

Answer (score -2):

try to add @EnableJpaRepositories and @ComponentScan  annotations in Application class to see if adding them solve your problem.

If still it doesn't work, add @Configuration in your CustomerRepository interface and then in Application class add @Import(CustomerRepository .class).

let me know if works.

Comment: The former shouldn't be neede. The latter is outright wrong. :)

Comment: I know the latter is not correct, it's just a way to identify if there is other kind of problem.

Comment: I tried your first advice (adding @EnableJpaRepositories and @ComponentScan) and it gives the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMapppingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!"

Comment: what spring version are you using?